# iOS/Swift: Two embedded views in UITableViewCell not appearing when run

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

am trying to embed a `UIStackView` inside of a `UITableViewCell`. Inside of the `UIStackView` should be two items: a `UICollectionView` and another `UITableView`.

The approach I am taking is to embed everything inside of a `UIView` contained in a root `UIViewController`.

[image: Storyboard]

I have created a `dataSource` outlet from the parent `UITableView` and made the root `UIViewController` conform to `UITableViewDataSource`. Afterwards, I implemented the standard `UITableView` functions and did a similar thing for the embedded `UICollectionView` in the `UITableViewCell`. Here is the code for the root `UIViewController` and custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
class OverviewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "AppTitle"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "appCell", for: indexPath) as! AppCell

        return cell
    }
}

class AppCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "featureCell", for: indexPath) as! AppCollectionCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

When I run this, I just get an empty table view:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add colorful backgrounds (red, blue, purple etc.) for all your views. So you'll be able to see which of them really appears and which aren't.

Comment: Also check your constraints. And add `print(/* something */)` methods into `numberOfItemsInSection`, to check if they was called or not.

Comment: It looks like the `UICollectionViewCell` is not showing up, nor is the `UICollectionView`'s `cellForItemAt` being called

Comment: Did you setup `dataSource` and `delegate` for all collection view and table view properly?

Comment: For the `UICollectionView`, do I create a `delegate` outlet to the `UIViewController`?

Comment: For `UICollectionView` `dataSource` and `delegate` will be `appCell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little project for you: https://github.com/mvdizel/q44833725

1. Use same dataSource's references as in project
2. Be careful with implementing data source methods

Your `top table view` has data source - your view controller.
Other one table view (inside the top table view cell) and collection view, both has data source - your cell.

Comment: When I make a `data source` outlet from `UICollectionView` to the parent `UITableView`, I get the runtime error `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Nevermind, my problem was I had the `reuseIdentifier` for the `UITableViewCell` and  the `UICollectionViewCell` mixed up.